# 412 (precondition failed) in Django

Tags: python, django, http, etag, http-status-code-412

I have this API endpoint which signs up a user and is used by mobile apps:

```
/mobile/v1/signup
```

I recently migrated the app from Django 1.7 to Django 1.10. After this I started to get this strange error. If this API accessed the second time, it is returning `412 (precondition failed)` error.

I searched the net and as long as I understand, the following happens:

The first time, the backend returns `Etag` in the response. Then, this `Etag` is then sent back to the server the second time this API is accessed. If this does not match, it returns `412`.

I solved this by manually setting a random value to the Etag header of the response of this API:

```
response['Etag'] = datetime.now().timestamp()
return response
```

But I don't think this is a good solution.

What is the proper way of solving this?

My middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'msd.middleware.RequestIdMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'apps.dashboard.middleware.DashboardMiddleware',
    'api.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]
```

UserAgentMiddleware:

```
class UserAgentMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    # A middleware that adds a "user_agent" object to request
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user_agent = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user_agent(request))
```

Comment: post your middlewares

Comment: @itzmeontv added the middleware

Comment: Try adding `django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware` to middlewares

Comment: @itzmeontv it did not help :(

Comment: Is there any custom middleware you are playing with response headers ?

Comment: @itzmeontv no, except for user agent. I posted it in the question